# Django Error NoReverseMatch at / - Django Pattern No Match Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I tried a lot of solution on internet and tried a lot of URL pattern but nothing working fine. here is my
**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'^category/(?P<cat>\w+)/$',views.categoryPage,name="category"),
re_path(r'^',views.home,name="index"),
]
```

**html link**

```
 <a class="nav-link" href='{% url "category" cat=mobiles %}'>Mobiles & Tablets <i class="fa fa-angle-down iconClr" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

and **views.py**

```
def categoryPage(request,cat):

    return render(request,'amazonApp/categoryItem.html',context={'category_name':cat})
```

**Error In Browser**

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'category' with keyword arguments '{'cat': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['category/<cat>']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'category' with keyword arguments '{'cat': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['category/<cat>']
Exception Location: C:\Users\DELL\Django\amazon_affiliate\env\lib\site- 
packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:   
C:\Users\DELL\Django\amazon_affiliate\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
]
```

I tried one Django [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#views-extra-options) solution, but it  didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need need to pass the argument to the url tag as a string literal

```
{% url "category" cat='mobiles' %}
```

You don't have a variable named `mobiles` in your context so when you use `cat=mobiles` this is being interpreted as `cat=''`

Comment: Can you explain me. What do you mean by passing string lateral? Please. Can you  write little bit code?

Comment: You don't have a variable named `mobiles`, you need to wrap in in quotes if you want to pass the string `'mobiles'`